# Можно ли регулировать количество ячеек в отдельном столбце grid-css?

Tags: html, css-grid

Пытаюсь сделать кнопочную панель web-калькулятора с помощью css-grid. Сама панель:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получилось сделать такую же. Вот разметка:

```
 <div class="button-table">

                <label>Математика</label>

                <input type="button" name="plus" id ="plus" value="+">
                <input type="button" name="minus" id ="minus" value="-">
                <input type="button" name="multiply" id ="multiply" value="*">
                <input type="button" name="divide" id ="divide" value="/">
                <input type="button" name="pow" id ="pow" value="x^y">


                <label>Алгебра</label>

                <input type="button" name="abs" id ="abs" value="abs">
                <input type="button" name="sort" id ="sort" value="sort">
                <input type="button" name="exp" id ="exp" value="exp">
                <input type="button" name="ln" id ="ln" value="ln">

                <label></label>



                <label>Тригонометрия</label>

                <input type="button" name="sin" id ="sin" value="sin">
                <input type="button" name="cos" id ="cos" value="cos">
                <input type="button" name="tg" id ="tg" value="tg">
                <input type="button" name="ctg" id ="ctg" value="ctg">

                <label></label>

                <label>Результат</label>

                <input type="button" name="accurate" id ="accurate" value="Точн.">
                <input type="button" name="cel" id ="cel" value="cel">
                <input type="button" name="floor" id ="floor" value="floor">
                <input type="button" name="round" id ="round" value="round">
                <input type="button" name="ce" id ="ce" value="ce">

            </div>
```

css:

```
.button-table {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
grid-auto-flow: column;
border: 12px;
border: solid;
border-color: red;

grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

Но смущает то, что "ненужные" ячейки во втором и третьем столбце пришлось занять пустыми `label`. Если их убрать из разметки панель получается такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-то отдельно отрегулировать размер второго и третьего столбца в grid, чтобы не использовать элементы-заглушки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно принудительно указать ряд для лэйблов

```css
.button-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  border: 12px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: red;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6,1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.button-table label{
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-table">

  <label>Математика</label>

  <input type="button" name="plus" id="plus" value="+">
  <input type="button" name="minus" id="minus" value="-">
  <input type="button" name="multiply" id="multiply" value="*">
  <input type="button" name="divide" id="divide" value="/">
  <input type="button" name="pow" id="pow" value="x^y">


  <label>Алгебра</label>

  <input type="button" name="abs" id="abs" value="abs">
  <input type="button" name="sort" id="sort" value="sort">
  <input type="button" name="exp" id="exp" value="exp">
  <input type="button" name="ln" id="ln" value="ln">




  <label>Тригонометрия</label>

  <input type="button" name="sin" id="sin" value="sin">
  <input type="button" name="cos" id="cos" value="cos">
  <input type="button" name="tg" id="tg" value="tg">
  <input type="button" name="ctg" id="ctg" value="ctg">


  <label>Результат</label>

  <input type="button" name="accurate" id="accurate" value="Точн.">
  <input type="button" name="cel" id="cel" value="cel">
  <input type="button" name="floor" id="floor" value="floor">
  <input type="button" name="round" id="round" value="round">
  <input type="button" name="ce" id="ce" value="ce">

</div>
```